# If I flip a coin repeatedly, will I get heads at some point?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If I flip a coin $n$ times, the probability that at least one toss was heads (H) is $1-1/2^n$. Taking $n\to\infty$ gives $1$. Does this prove that if I toss a coin repeatedely I will at some point get H?

Comment: There exists an outcome in which you never get heads, but the probability of this event is 0. Whether you should interpret this as truly impossible is more of a philosophical question than a mathematical one.

Comment: I do not agree with Karl's claim that it is a philosophical question. *No matter what* your infinite sequence of (fair) coin flips yields in terms of heads and tails, the probability of getting that exact sequence is 0.  Therefore every possible sequence of H's and T's is indeed possible (in the ideal mathematical model) — and equally unlikely.

Comment: @DanAsimov  Your assertion that a particular mathematical model captures the OPs question about "reality"  is a philosophical one, not a mathematical one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a space $X=\{H, T\}^\mathbb{N}$ of infinite sequences of coin flips, equipped with probability measure that assigns $\operatorname{Pr}[x_i = H] = \frac{1}{2}$ for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$. In this space, the event $\{(T, T, T, T, \dots)\}$ (just getting tails for ever) has probability zero. That means that the formalism of probability theory cannot distinguish between this event and the empty event. So either you have to decide to call this event impossible, or else you have to come up with a different definition of impossible.

The event $\{(T, T, T, T, \dots)\}$ is what [this old reddit post](https://old.reddit.com/r/math/comments/8mcz8y/notions_of_impossible_in_probability_theory/) calls a "topologically possible" but "measurably impossible" (probability zero) event. The post argues that topological impossibility has a lot of issues as a definition, so maybe we really ought to interpret probability-zero as actually meaning impossible, though this seems not to be universally agreed upon.

Comment: However, the sequence H, T, H, T, H, T, ... has the same probability even though it does not violate the expected occurrence of H or T.